# Unable to lock screen in Unity 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, lock-screen

I used to be able to lock the screen, but suddenly it doesn't work anymore. When I close my lid, the screen isn't locked. When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>. If I click the menu in the upper right of the screen, there is no lock button. And when I go to "Brightness & Lock" in settings, the "Lock" section is just disabled.

What has happened? Am I missing a package?

Comment: Did you try _super+L_ (sorry, typing from my phone)

Comment: Super+L has the same result as Ctrl+Alt+L